# Need help avoiding double vertical scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am running into an issue with a Disqus iframe inside a div I have within the class "wrapper." It shows a scrollbar, even though the browser itself has a scrollbar for the large image that's also in the browser.

**HTML**

```
<section id="commentContainer" class="darkbgType">
    <div id="commentPane">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2 class="pbxl">File Title</h2>
            <!--Disqus-->
            <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
                var disqus_shortname = 'inspectacle'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
                var disqus_identifier = '@file.fileHash';
                /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
                (function() {
                    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                    dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                })();
            </script>
            <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
            <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a><!--end Disqus-->
        </div><!--end wrapper-->    
    </div><!--end commentPane-->
</section><!--end commentContainer-->
```

**CSS**

```
#commentContainer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#commentPane {
    background: #181818;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 24px 40px 40px;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `overflow:auto`, which means you're telling the browser that it should use scrollbars whenever there is an overflow.

If you only want to limit scrolling to a single axis, use `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`.

[Edit] The double scrollbars is due to the height of the document body being stretch beyond viewport size of 100%, because you have added *additional* padding on top of 100% assigned to `#commentPane`. I suggest that you use `border-box: box-sizing` such that the final height includes both the border width (if any) and the padding you have included.

Comment: Hi Terry, I am talking about the double y-axis scrollbars in the screenshot I shared above.

Comment: That is because you have sent the height of the `#commentPane` to 100% AND added additional padding, causing the document to stretch beyond the viewport.

Try using `box-sizing: border-box`, which will cause the browser to factor in the padding when calculating height, therefore fixing it at 100% regardless of the border width and padding size.

Comment: ...and where is this mysterious screenshot?

Comment: This is silly. You don't remove your question when it has been solved. Flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working as it should if I am looking at it correctly. The comments do not fit vertically in their container and a scrollbar is shown for them. The image on the left is too large and thus a scrollbar is on the right side of the browser to scroll through the page.

My only assumption is you do not want a scrollbar on the comments which would require `overflow-y: hidden` for that container.

Comment: Right, but then comments would not all show in that container with that implementation :(